# Is it possible to revert roll back to minor versions of a component and are these stored anywhere?

Tags: 2013-sp1, workflow, content-manager

I'm sure this is a stupid question but I was just wondering if it was possible to roll back a component to one of its minor revisions. They aren't stored in the history on the CM and also I checked the CM database and it only seems to store major revisions and the latest minor revision. So I'm thinking it's not possible but I am hoping that I'm just looking in the wrong place.

The reason I ask is that we are rolling out a workflow where the first task we are telling a user to perform (after creating the initial blank page and component) is to start workflow so that they then own the document and nobody else can make edits. However if I am correct and they can't roll back to minor revisions then they potentially could wipe their document and have no way of recovering it.

Thanks in advance for any help/answers!

Comment: For a given user working on content or pages, this minor version is a lot like a document or spreadsheet. You can make changes to an item while it's open, but those changes are lost if you don't save. The bigger concern with Tridion Workflow is when someone _else_ takes ownership of your items (hence the "are you sure?" warning to someone taking ownership of items).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to rollback to minor versions as they are just **Work In Progress** for a given item while it is checked out by a given user. So, it is not possible to revert to any minor version. Infact the changes will be lost if you don't save the changes as Alvin pointed out.
Alternative suggestion for your use case:

> When you start the workflow you can allow the user to create major
>   version which can be sent for editorial approval. If that is approved,
>   go ahead or if rejected the user can alter it again and create a new
>   version. As far as I remember you can checkout the item so that no one
>   other than system admin can override the lock on the item.

If creating more versions is a concern you can always purge old versions.

Comment: Depending on how (Bundle) workflow is used, this approach could also be adapted to end workflow to create major versions Or different workflows can handle approval/review vs publishing since the minimum approval status is respected outside of Workflow.